# How often is the flair image getting re-generated?

Tags: support, flair

So I changed my profile picture. And my display name. After some time the picture in the profile and on the top bar got updated (took about 15 minutes). But the flair picture is still old.

How long does it take to get it refreshed?

I fully expect that the answer may be "it takes less time than getting this question answered", but still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours - it is heavily cached on both the server and client side.